# I need to scrape the page of this video and retrieve the caption of the video

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

The selector that I find in the html code of the page is not found whenever I try to run the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@jrocssj/video/7134394312397327662"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Replace with the path to your webdriver executable
driver.get(url)

try:
    # Wait for the div element to become visible for up to 20 seconds
    div_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tiktok-1fo8i23-DivContainer ejg0rhn0"))
    )

    span_elem = div_elem.find_element_by_css_selector("span.tiktok-j2a19r-SpanText.efbd9f0")
    
    if span_elem is not None:
        caption = span_elem.text.strip()
        print(caption)
    else:
        print("Span element not found.")
except:
    print("Div element not found or timed out.")
finally:
    driver.quit()  # Close the browser window
```

I tried to try different selectors but to no avail. They are never found.

Answer (score 0):

The element is blocked by other elements, so it is not directly visible. As such, you should use `EC.presence_of_element_located` and read the `textContent` instead. (There should also be no space in the first CSS selector.)

```py
div_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tiktok-1fo8i23-DivContainer.ejg0rhn0"))
)
span_elem = div_elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.tiktok-j2a19r-SpanText.efbd9f0")
caption = span_elem.get_attribute('textContent').strip()
```